# Story about a house with a supernatural door

Tags: story-identification

I read this story online, sometime between 2009 and 2012.

The story was told as a series of blog posts, emails and text messages between two individuals, the narrator, and their friend, who had recently purchased a house. It's also possible the narrator *was* the purchaser, corresponding with someone else, but I'm not entirely certain.

Nevertheless, the two characters lived a fair distance apart, hence why they only talked remotely. I think the first post explained the blog exists as a record of what happened.

The purchaser of the house discovers a strange door that couldn't be opened, and didn't seem like it should lead anywhere. Moreover, they noted that the door wasn't always present. Sometimes it would be there, and other times it wouldn't be, mysteriously vanishing.

The two characters corresponded about the new house, the narrator being skeptical, until the purchaser finally invites the narrator to come visit and see the mysterious door for him or herself.

While en route, a series of text messages from the purchaser begin getting stranger and stranger, finally cumulating in a series of text messages that read nothing more than:

> THE DOOR IS OPEN
>  THE DOOR IS OPEN
>  THE DOOR IS OPEN

I believe that's where the story ended - the narrator never found the house nor their vanished friend, and the blog now exists as the only record of their disappearance.

I haven't been able to find it, and I suspect where ever it was posted is no longer online.

Still, I would be curious if anyone here could track it down. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an [SCP Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP_Foundation) candidate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some aspects of the question immediately reminded me of "[The Dionaea House](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheDionaeaHouse)" (beware: tvtropes link). This was one of the first "creepypastas", told using a mixture of different media: emails, text messages, and linked web journals. The story was developed from 2004 - 2006 by Eric Heisserer, and was later pitched as a movie project, but without success.

The story open with *Correspondence from Mark Condry*, which takes place in September-October 2004 and consists of an email correspondence between Mark and Eric about their childhood friend Drew. From this [webpage](https://courseofhorror.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/the-door-is-open-the-dionaea-house/):

> Mark soon finds himself obsessed with understanding what drove Drew
> over the edge, unintentionally drawing Eric into the investigation as
> well.  Together Mark and Eric remember bits and pieces about Drew from
> five years ago when he was a part of their Saturday game night gang –
> in particular, the drastic personality change in Drew after
> house-sitting a place for two weeks that his stepfather owned.
> Following the trail of these half-forgotten memories, Mark finds the
> house that altered Drew.  And what Mark and later Eric learn is that
> the house is not all it appears to be – harboring characteristics
> that, according to Mark, are reminiscent of the alluring but dangerous
> carnivorous plant, the Venus fly trap.

The original website where the story was housed, http://www.dionaea-house.com/ is sadly no more, but the text can be found using the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180116045845/http://www.dionaea-house.com/) or the [creepypasta fandom](https://creepypasta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dionaea_House) site. In particular the entry for Tuesday, September 21 2004 consists of just the sentence:

> THE DOOR IS OPEN

Comment: The details were a lot more elaborate than I remembered, but given the key phrase at the end, this is definitely it. Thank you!

Comment: I was also right that the original was taken offline.